# django-mptt - How to set different models in the same tree

Tags: django, django-mptt

I would like to have a tree that would mimic a file system with folders and files. Folders and files would be defined by different models with different fields attributes.

models:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Folder(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class File(MPTTModel):
    parent= TreeForeignKey(Document)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    encoding = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Creating some folders and files:

```
 from shapefile.models import Folder, File
 root = Folder.objects.create(name="Root")
 download = Folder.objects.create(name="Download", parent=root)
 upload = Folder.objects.create(name="Upload", parent=root)
 File.objects.create(filename="Test", encoding="UTF-8", parent=download)
```

Shoul have:

```
> Root
> --Download
> ----Test
> --Upload
```

How can I retrieve this tree in view and template?

**Edit:**

Files are not inserted as folder's nodes:

```
file = File.objects.get(filename="Test")
file.get_ancestors()
>>> []
```

Comment: maybe consider this one too: https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic-tree

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine the MPTTModel with a [generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)
from the *contenttypes framework*.
You can enable it by adding 'django.contrib.contenttypes' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class TreeItem(MPTTModel):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class File(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    encoding = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The [mptt documentacion](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates.html) explains how to access the tree in your templates.